# Python shell showing error but cmd is running that program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python.I am doing addition of two numbers in cmd using input parameter .I am getting output on cmd but  getting Error on python shell.I am using windows 7 and python shell 3.3.2 . so anyone can tell me why my code is not running on python shell ?

code:

```
import sys
n=int(sys.argv[1])
m=int(sys.argv[2])
print(n+m)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/pythonprogram/add.py",  line 4, in
>
> ```
> n=int(sys.argv[1])
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you running your program with correct amount of arguments? Please show how you are running the script in shell

Comment: when i run the above code its showing error . do python shell takes parameter like cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` contains the command line parameters. When you run your script in the Python shell you're most likely not sending any parameters. I would suggest adding a check if there are command line arguments present like this:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    n=int(sys.argv[1])
    m=int(sys.argv[2])  
    print(n+m)
```

Check [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv) out to find out more about Python and `sys.argv`

Comment: **What exactly** is the problem?

Comment: `sys.argv` always contains at least one element. You have to check for at least 3 items in that case.

Comment: @Euphe Right, fixed it

Comment: If you're using `IDLE`, then no, it's not possible to provide command line arguments.

Comment: anyway to run it on python shell?

Comment: @samd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148994/when-running-a-python-script-in-idle-is-there-a-way-to-pass-in-command-line-arg

Answer (score 0):

Your program is expecting two **command line arguments**. 
`sys.argv` is a **list** of command line arguments. The error `IndexError: list index out of range` is telling you that you tried to get list item number 2, (with index 1), but the list doesn't have that many values.

You can reproduce that error in the shell:

```
>> alist = ['Item 0']
>> print(alist[1])
```

Since alist only has item with index 0 requesting items with higher indexes will cause that error.

Now, to your exact problem. The program is telling you it expected command line arguments, but they were not provided. Provide them!
Run this command:

```
python add.py 1 2
```

This will execute the script and pass `1` as the first argument, `2` as the second argument. 
In your case the general format is

```
python add.py [n] [m]
```

Now at that point you might be (you should be) wondering what `sys.argv[0]` is then, any why your `n` number doesn't get assigned to `sys.argv[1]`. 
`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script running.

Further reading on command line arguments:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

**Additional.**
You could modify your script to be more descriptive:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3: #script name + 2 other arguments required
 print("Provide at least two numbers")
else:
 n=int(sys.argv[1])
 m=int(sys.argv[2])
 print(n+m)
```