# Open IDLE and run module through VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel, python-idle

I know how to use VBA to run a python script through cmd, and I know how to use VBA to open IDLE, but is it possible to make a module in VBA that will open a python script in IDLE and automatically run that python script? Here's my code for opening IDLE via VBA and cmd (but it doesn't run the script):

```
Sub runidlefrompython()

Dim args As String

args = "C:\users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.py"

Shell "cmd.exe /S /K" & "C:\Users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" & " " & args & " -r " & "C:\PythonPrograms\Hello.py", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: also, would it be possible to add something to the python script itself to make it run automatically when IDLE is opened?

Comment: From [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148994/when-running-a-python-script-in-idle-is-there-a-way-to-pass-in-command-line-arg), I would say `Shell "cmd.exe /S /K" & "C:\Users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" & " " & args & " -r " & "C:\PythonPrograms\Hello.py", vbNormalFocus`

Comment: when i do that, i get an "invalid argument" error

Comment: nvm it worked! I just needed to put a space before and after the "-r". Thank you @Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Create `Example.py` with one word only (remove the parenthesis, if you are working with Python2):

```
print ("Hello World!")
```

Then try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim args As String
    args = "C:\somePath"
    Shell "cmd.exe /S /K" & args & "\Example.py", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by PythonFind?

Comment: @EvanFleisig - it is just a directory.

Comment: so I'm literally writing PythonFind? and when you say "somePath", does that mean I'm finding the path to python.exe?

Comment: @EvanFleisig - see the update. The file "Example.py" should be in `C:\somePath`.  Nothing in my answer is related to the path to "python.exe".